# using script in a variable

Tags: sql-server, declare

Can you declare a variable, set it as a script definition and then execute it repeatedly throughout your script? I understand how to set a variable to the result of a script, but I want to re-use the definition itself. This is because I want to occasionally get the count from a script and sometimes the top result throughout the rest of my script and I want to make it so the script is easily customized by only needing to change the script once at the beginning.

**An example:**

```
declare @RepeatScript nvarchar(200)

declare @count int

declare @topresult int

set @RepeatScript = ' from Table1 where something = 1 and something else > getdate()-5'

set @count = select count(ID) & @RepeatScript

set @topresult = select top 1 (ID) & @RepeatScript
```

This very simple case would be simple to fix, but if I wanted to reference the same set of information multiple times without having to create and drop a temp_table over and over, this would be very helpful. I do this kind of thing in MS Access all the time, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it in SSMS.

Comment: Simply put no, you can't do this. But if you want to access the result of the same query more than once you should store the result in a variable instead of doing the same query over and over. To accomplish something like you are demonstrating would require dynamic sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @RepeatScript nvarchar(200)

declare @count varchar(200)

declare @topresult varchar(200)

set @RepeatScript = ' from Table1 where something = 1 and something else > getdate()-5'

set @count = 'select count(ID) '+@RepeatScript+''

set @topresult = 'select top 1 (ID)'+@RepeatScript+''

print (@count)
print (@topresult)
```

Something like that? but instead of using print you would be using exec to run the select statement. Does that help?

Comment: This gets me the information I want if executed, but if I want to reference it in a script it doesn't work. If I wanted to use "Select * from table2 where ID = @topresult" it doesn't seem to work. The general idea is to be able to nest select statements into other statements repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeatedly run these queries. You don't even need to run more than 1 query to capture this information. This will capture both pieces of data in a single query. You can then reference that information anywhere else within the current batch. This meets your criteria of simply changing the script at the beginning.

```
declare @count int
    , @topresult int

select @count = count(ID)
    , @topresult = MAX(ID) --MAX would the same thing as top 1 order by ID desc
from Table1 
where something = 1
```

Comment: I didn't know you could write it this way and referencing the variables in this method does make life easier. In my situation I would still have to repeat though because I want the topresult to be before I run an update statement and the count to be after the update (it has an effect on the statement). This is very helpful for much of my script though.